Javascript window.print() problem - text quality
I am working on cash register software and now I have problems with receipt printing.
I use php to load receipt data in a html div which I want to print. So I use javascript for printing and everything works, but the print quality is weird. I have also a logo printed on the receipt which is fine but the texts are printed pixelated or with white dots. I know it's not the printer problem, because it prints receipts from another software nicely and it prints the logo without any problems as well.
main file where the receipt is loaded and printed:
I am sorry for my language I use in the code. (uctenka = receipt)
<?php
session_start();
require_once("assets/connection.php");

if (isset($_GET["uctenkaID"])) {
    $uctenkaID = $_GET["uctenkaID"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pokladní systém od ROYAL-PRINTU</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylePrint.css">
</head>
<div class='uctenkaTisk d-flex flex-column justify-content-between align-items-start' id="uctenkaTisk">
    <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-3">
        <?php include "assets/uctenkaLogo.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <?php include "assets/uctenkaInfo.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 uctenkaPolozky my-3">
        <?php include "assets/zobrazitUctenku.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 uctenkaShrnuti">
        <?php include "assets/zobrazitUctenkuShrnuti.php"; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // window.onload = function() {
    //     window.print();
    //     window.onafterprint = function() {
    //         window.close();
    //     };
    // };
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>


This is how everything is styled:
I use also bootstrap.
Please notice that I use <span> for texts, because I have already tried <p> and it didn't work.
.uctenkaTisk {
    visibility: visible !important;
    width: 80mm !important;
}
.uctenkaTisk span {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif  !important;
    font-size: 3.2mm !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
.uctenkaInfoText{
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 3mm !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .uctenkaTisk, .uctenkaTisk * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .uctenkaTisk {
        width: 80mm !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .uctenkaTisk span {
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif  !important;
        font-size: 3.2mm !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
    .uctenkaInfoText{
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 3mm !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
}


"but the texts are printed pixelated or with white dots" - could it be the font itself? Can you try switching to something else and see if that helps?

Otherwise, how about trying something very simple. Just <h1>Test</h1>, no CSS or anything else. Does that look okay? If so, add complexity. Repeat until solved or you find the culprit.

I have tried but the print problem is still the same. Preview dialog is showing everything all right, but the real print has only the text printed bad, the logo is fine.

Okay, assuming your comment means you tried a very simple example like I showed, I think we can rule out PHP since that's not involved (regardless of the file extension of the script). We can probably rule out CSS, too. I think it might be best to update the question with the simplest example of what looks bad/wrong, ideally just a single line of HTML. Keeping the note about the image is important still though, that's indeed weird.

What happens when you run the code on different systems, different browsers, different printers etc? i.e. I assume it's not something as simple as the browser settings for that printer being draft quality?

I found a solution so I want to share it here if someone would have similar problem.
If you are using a thermal receipt B&W printer, make sure everything what you're trying to print has 100% black color. So in this case, the problem was, that texts were not black, but just some kind of dark gray which resulted in white dots on the print.
The main reason of bad color was bootstrap, so the solution is forcing the text to be black by adding color: black !important in stylesheet.
